# splitting lemma in $C^*$ algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In abelian category,there is a splitting lemma. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma

I wonder whether the splitting lemma also holds in $C^*$ algebras .Is left split equivalent to right split?

Comment: This question is very similar to:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848612/c-algebra-has-a-nonzero-finite-dimensional-quotient/2848630#comment5883332_2848630

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not even if the C$^*$-algebra is commutative. For instance if you take $A=C_b(\mathbb N)$ (bounded sequences), then $I=c_0(\mathbb N)$ is an ideal that is not complemented.

Comment: If $A$ has a unit ,$I$ is a finite dimensional ideal,can we decompose it?

Comment: Not sure. I'll think about it.

Comment: But that's not what you were asking. If you are given $A$ and $B$, you can form $E=A\oplus B$. Your question is about having  $B$ and $E$ and finding $A$.

Comment: And what would $A/I$ be if you don't know $I$?

Comment: a typo,If $I$ and $A/I$ were given,$E_1=I \oplus A/I$

Comment: The point of the splitting lemma is that you don't get to choose $E_1$, it is given to you.

Comment: Pro Argerami,if I and $A/I$ were given,can we call $0\rightarrow I \rightarrow A\rightarrow A/I\rightarrow 0$ the extension of $A/I$ by $I$?

Comment: Yes, the usual terminology is that $A$ is an extension of $A/I$ by $I$.