# Can $C^*$ algebra $A$ be decomposed?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a $C^*$ algebra ,$B$ is a finite dimensional $C^*$ subalgebra of $A$.Does there exists a $*$ subalgebra of $C$ such that $A=B \oplus C$?

Comment: [What am I, a goldfish?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2859200/328173)

Comment: It's not a joke, but rather an accusation that you posted the same question twice and hoped that nobody would notice.

Comment: I was calling myself.

Comment: How is it impolite? Goldfish are so cute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In such an algebra $A$, both $B$ and $C$ would be nontrivial ideals. So if you take any simple C$^*$-algebra that has finite-dimensional subalgebras, your decomposition does not exist.

Such an example could be $A=$UHF$(2^\infty)$, which has lots of projections. Take a nontrivial projection $p\in A$, and put $B=\mathbb C\, p$. Then $B$ is one-dimensional but not an ideal, and thus the decomposition does not exit.

Any other simple real rank zero example would do.